# Understanding behavior with gdb

Tags: c++, gdb, boost-asio

For the past month I'm hunting down this problem, but I couldn't figured out. I have this gdb log that is the main thread.

I was using Boost 1.53 before so I was thinking that it may be a race condition on Boost epoll_wait then I updated to Boost 1.58, but couldn't fix the issue.

```
    Thread 1 (Thread 0x7ffff7fe4740 (LWP 21665)):
#0  0x00007ffff7b14a13 in epoll_wait ()
    at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
No locals.
#1  0x0000000000538cd7 in boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::run(bool, boost::asio::detail::op_queue<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation>&) [clone .constprop.204] (this=0x4, block=<optimized out>, ops=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/epoll_reactor.ipp:392
        timeout = <optimized out>
        events = {{events = 1, data = {ptr = 0xb0b3c0, fd = 11580352, 
            u32 = 11580352, u64 = 11580352}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 4623520, 
            data = {ptr = 0xaa7bd800000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 47986913683963904}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x8c81e0, 
            fd = 9208288, u32 = 9208288, u64 = 9208288}}, {events = 0, 
            data = {ptr = 0x56ec2b00000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 24466517424865280}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x7fffffffd820, fd = -10208, u32 = 4294957088, 
            u64 = 140737488345120}}, {events = 5, data = {
            ptr = 0x736f6c6300000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 8317986209234157568}}, {events = 101, data = {ptr = 0x0, 
            fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 11585136, data = {
            ptr = 0x2700000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 167503724544}}, {
            events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x27, fd = 39, u32 = 39, u64 = 39}}, {
            events = 0, data = {ptr = 0xdfaf1000000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 62961403060813824}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x20, 
            fd = 32, u32 = 32, u64 = 32}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x63d42000000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 28099256598396928}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x31, 
            fd = 49, u32 = 49, u64 = 49}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x0, 
            fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x0, 
            fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 4294957792, data = {
            ptr = 0xaa1b2800007fff, fd = 32767, u32 = 32767, 
            u64 = 47880604653486079}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0xaa1b20, 
            fd = 11148064, u32 = 11148064, u64 = 11148064}}, {
            events = 11148096, data = {ptr = 0xb0c61000000000, fd = 0, 
            u32 = 0, u64 = 49757367922851840}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x4f46bc <Protocol::disconnect() const+76>, fd = 5195452, 
            u32 = 5195452, u64 = 5195452}}, {events = 4222451713, data = {
            ptr = 0xffffdae000000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 18446703254340370432}}, {events = 2, data = {
            ptr = 0x7fffffffdae0, fd = -9504, u32 = 4294957792, 
            u64 = 140737488345824}}, {events = 11148080, data = {
            ptr = 0xaa7bd800000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 47986913683963904}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x5342b8 <ProtocolLogin::onRecvFirstMessage(NetworkMessage&)+808>, fd = 5456568, u32 = 5456568, u64 = 5456568}}, {events = 4294957808, 
            data = {ptr = 0xffffdae000007fff, fd = 32767, u32 = 32767, 
            u64 = 18446703254340403199}}, {events = 32767, data = {
            ptr = 0x7fffffffdaf0, fd = -9488, u32 = 4294957808, 
            u64 = 140737488345840}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0xb00000000, 
            fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 47244640256}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0xa1, fd = 161, u32 = 161, u64 = 161}}, {
            events = 4158462776, data = {ptr = 0xffffd97000007fff, fd = 32767, 
            u32 = 32767, u64 = 18446701673792438271}}, {events = 32767, 
            data = {ptr = 0x7ffff7dd1b70 <main_arena+80>, fd = -136504464, 
            u32 = 4158462832, u64 = 140737351850864}}, {events = 9873, 
            data = {ptr = 0xffffd96fffff8000, fd = -32768, u32 = 4294934528, 
            u64 = 18446701673792372736}}, {events = 32767, data = {
            ptr = 0x7fffffffd98f, fd = -9841, u32 = 4294957455, 
            u64 = 140737488345487}}, {events = 96, data = {
            ptr = 0xa100000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 691489734656}}, {
            events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x7fffffffd9d0, fd = -9776, 
            u32 = 4294957520, u64 = 140737488345552}}, {events = 6314788, 
            data = {ptr = 0x5b00000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 390842023936}}, 
        {events = 16777326, data = {ptr = 0x1300000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 81604378624}}, {events = 9777, data = {
            ptr = 0xffffd9cfffff8000, fd = -32768, u32 = 4294934528, 
            u64 = 18446702086109233152}}, {events = 32767, data = {
            ptr = 0x2, fd = 2, u32 = 2, u64 = 2}}, {events = 4155593625, 
            data = {ptr = 0x7fff, fd = 32767, u32 = 32767, u64 = 32767}}, {
            events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x605bc5 <boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_recv_op_base<boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1>::do_perform(boost::asio::detail::reactor_op*)+389>, fd = 6314949, u32 = 6314949, u64 = 6314949}}, {events = 91, data = {
            ptr = 0x100006e, fd = 16777326, u32 = 16777326, 
            u64 = 16777326}}, {events = 19, data = {ptr = 0x60, fd = 96, 
            u32 = 96, u64 = 96}}, {events = 161, data = {
            ptr = 0xffffda4000000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 18446702567145603072}}, {events = 32767, data = {
            ptr = 0x18, fd = 24, u32 = 24, u64 = 24}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0xffff8000000025c1, fd = 9665, u32 = 9665, 
            u64 = 18446603336221205953}}, {events = 4294957631, data = {
            ptr = 0x200007fff, fd = 32767, u32 = 32767, u64 = 8589967359}}, {
            events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x7ffff7b15399 <recvmsg+57>, 
            fd = -139373671, u32 = 4155593625, u64 = 140737348981657}}, {
            events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x605b2400000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 27121807941173248}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x100006e0000005b, fd = 91, u32 = 91, 
            u64 = 72058066484330587}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x8ede7500000013, fd = 19, u32 = 19, 
            u64 = 40214040785453075}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x2, 
            fd = 2, u32 = 2, u64 = 2}}, {events = 2, data = {
            ptr = 0x8f3f6800000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 40320637578772480}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x0, 
            fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0xffffda3000000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 18446702498426126336}}, {events = 32767, data = {
            ptr = 0x1, fd = 1, u32 = 1, u64 = 1}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 9363024, 
            data = {ptr = 0xc4a82a3000000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 14170622613168062464}}, {events = 32767, data = {
            ptr = 0xb0b9e0, fd = 11581920, u32 = 11581920, u64 = 11581920}}, 
        {events = 9387880, data = {ptr = 0xb0b3e800000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 49737404914860032}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x13, 
            fd = 19, u32 = 19, u64 = 19}}, {events = 82, data = {
            ptr = 0x8c84f000000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 39552663066509312}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x61a9c5 <boost::asio::async_read<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (Connection::*)(boost::system::error_code const&)> (std::shared_ptr<Connection>, std::_Placeholder<1>)> >(boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >&, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1 const&, std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (Connection::*)(boost::system::error_code const&)> (std::shared_ptr<Connection>, std::_Placeholder<1>)>&&) [clone .constprop.610]+901>, fd = 6400453, u32 = 6400453, u64 = 6400453}}, {
            events = 365290, data = {ptr = 0x1300000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 81604378624}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, 
            u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 5702176, data = {
            ptr = 0xffffdc5000000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 18446704834888335360}}, {events = 32767, data = {
            ptr = 0x61ec35 <boost::date_time::microsec_clock<boost::posix_time::ptime>::create_time(tm* (*)(long const*, tm*)) [clone .constprop.632]+53>, 
            fd = 6417461, u32 = 6417461, u64 = 6417461}}, {
            events = 4294957856, data = {ptr = 0xb0b9e000007fff, fd = 32767, 
            u32 = 32767, u64 = 49743967624921087}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0xb0b9e0, fd = 11581920, u32 = 11581920, u64 = 11581920}}, 
        {events = 6397484, data = {ptr = 0x8f3f6800000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 40320637578772480}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x8ede75, 
            fd = 9363061, u32 = 9363061, u64 = 9363061}}, {events = 2, 
            data = {ptr = 0x100000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 4294967296}}, {
            events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {
            events = 5702176, data = {ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {
            events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {
            events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x300000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 12884901888}}, {events = 261, data = {ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, 
            u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 9363040, data = {
            ptr = 0x8ede5000000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 40213881871663104}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x468ca0 <__pthread_key_create@plt>, fd = 4623520, 
            u32 = 4623520, u64 = 4623520}}, {events = 9209824, data = {
            ptr = 0xffffdbe000000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 18446704353851998208}}, {events = 32767, data = {
            ptr = 0x8f3f08, fd = 9387784, u32 = 9387784, u64 = 9387784}}, {
            events = 5700037, data = {ptr = 0x100000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 4294967296}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0xa8db00, 
            fd = 11066112, u32 = 11066112, u64 = 11066112}}, {
            events = 9363061, data = {ptr = 0x200000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 8589934592}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0xa8db00, 
            fd = 11066112, u32 = 11066112, u64 = 11066112}}, {
            events = 6396619, data = {ptr = 0x57022000000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 24490659436036096}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x0, 
            fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x0, 
            fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x7fffffffdc50, fd = -9136, u32 = 4294958160, 
            u64 = 140737488346192}}, {events = 9363040, data = {
            ptr = 0x8f3f0800000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 40320225261912064}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x1, 
            fd = 1, u32 = 1, u64 = 1}}, {events = 6, data = {
            ptr = 0xffffdc5000000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 18446704834888335360}}, {events = 32767, data = {
            ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 5702335, 
            data = {ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 0, 
            data = {ptr = 0x8c81e0, fd = 9208288, u32 = 9208288, 
            u64 = 9208288}}, {events = 4294958176, data = {
            ptr = 0x700007fff, fd = 32767, u32 = 32767, u64 = 30064803839}}, 
        {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0xa544f61727541, fd = 1634891073, 
            u32 = 1634891073, u64 = 2907449681147201}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x7fffffffdd60, fd = -8864, u32 = 4294958432, 
            u64 = 140737488346464}}, {events = 9208240, data = {
            ptr = 0x100000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 4294967296}}, {
            events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {
            events = 9208288, data = {ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {
            events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x6080d0 <boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_recv_op<boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (Connection::*)(boost::system::error_code const&)> (std::shared_ptr<Connection>, std::_Placeholder<1>)> > >::do_complete(boost::asio::detail::task_io_service*, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation*, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long)+352>, fd = 6324432, 
            u32 = 6324432, u64 = 6324432}}, {events = 11581168, data = {
            ptr = 0xb0b6e000000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 49740669090004992}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0xb0a2e08000001f, fd = -2147483617, u32 = 2147483679, 
            u64 = 49718681004933151}}, {events = 4155593625, data = {
            ptr = 0xffffdd6000007fff, fd = 32767, u32 = 32767, 
            u64 = 18446706003119472639}}, {events = 32767, data = {
            ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 19, data = {
            ptr = 0x8f3f68, fd = 9387880, u32 = 9387880, u64 = 9387880}}, {
            events = 9363061, data = {ptr = 0x200000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 8589934592}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, 
            u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 2, data = {ptr = 0x57022000000000, 
            fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 24490659436036096}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 9363040, 
            data = {ptr = 0x8ede5000000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 40213881871663104}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x0, 
            fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 4146303200, data = {
            ptr = 0x60afc100007fff, fd = 32767, u32 = 32767, 
            u64 = 27214841227804671}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x7fffcb192880, fd = -887543680, u32 = 3407423616, 
            u64 = 140736600811648}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x8f3f6800000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 40320637578772480}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x7fffffffddb0, fd = -8784, u32 = 4294958512, 
            u64 = 140737488346544}}, {events = 9208240, data = {
            ptr = 0x60879e00000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 27170710438805504}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x8ede60, 
            fd = 9363040, u32 = 9363040, u64 = 9363040}}, {events = 9363024, 
            data = {ptr = 0xffffddb000000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 18446706346716823552}}, {events = 32767, data = {
            ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x0, fd = 0, u32 = 0, u64 = 0}}, {events = 0, data = {
            ptr = 0x60afb0 <Connection::handleTimeout(std::weak_ptr<Connection>, boost::system::error_code const&)>, fd = 6336432, u32 = 6336432, 
            u64 = 6336432}}, {events = 9363040, data = {
            ptr = 0x8ede5000000000, fd = 0, u32 = 0, 
            u64 = 40213881871663104}}, {events = 0, data = {ptr = 0x7d, 
            fd = 125, u32 = 125, u64 = 125}}}
        num_events = <optimized out>
        check_timers = <optimized out>
#2  0x0000000000551743 in do_run_one (ec=..., this_thread=..., lock=..., 
    this=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp:356
No locals.
#3  run (ec=..., this=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp:149
        this_thread = {private_op_queue = {front_ = 0x0, back_ = 0x0}, 
        private_outstanding_work = 0}
        ctx = {key_ = 0x8c81b0, value_ = 0x7fffffffde70, next_ = 0x0}
        lock = {mutex_ = @0x8c81e0, locked_ = true}
#4  _ZN5boost4asio10io_service3runEv.isra.200 ()
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/impl/io_service.ipp:59
        ec = {m_val = 0, m_cat = 0x7ffff72390e0}
#5  ServiceManager::run() (this=<optimized out>)
    at /home/server/sources/src/server.cpp:46
No locals.
#6  0x000000000046c3c4 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe138)
    at /home/server/sources/src/otserv.cpp:94
        serviceManager = {acceptors = std::unordered_map with 2 elements, 
        io_service = {service_registry_ = 0x8c8160, impl_ = @0x8c81b0}, 
        signals = {set = {<No data fields>}}, 
        death_timer = {<No data fields>}, running = true}
        __func__ = "main"
(gdb)
```

Has anyone ever that reported this issue before and is available to share the experience? **This issue only happens once a day, and in production**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @olivecoder There isn't any more information that I can provided, because I couldn't find anything more.

Comment: I don't think it is feasible to give you an answer based on an optimized out gdb backtrace output only. You are investigating this for a month, having access to the gdb console and the source code and you weren't.

Comment: All I can do is give you generic obvious recommendations: turn off optimizations, debug the core dump, stare at the code, check the known bugs of your dependencies...

Comment: What is the source code (is it [opentibia](https://github.com/opentibia/server/blob/master/src/otserv.cpp))? What is the problem? The backtrace looks ok.

Comment: Did your code receive a signal? Which one? Sent by which process? Have you checked your available memory at the time of the crash (if there was a crash)?

Comment: @olivecoder Could you please recommend me some page to see better how to do thoses things that you recommended? Never did. It received a SIGINT on epoll_wait(). It wasn't a crash, I forced the issue with CTRL + C, because the process just stop works and the Website goes down.

Comment: SIGINT is the consequence of your ctrl-c. Anyway, now we at least know what the problem is as it could be a SEGFAULT (the most common causes for crashes) or the OOM killer or anything else.

Comment: @KamilCuk You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/otland/forgottenserver), and here is my [otserv.cpp](https://pastebin.com/CMtDDL7m)

Comment: Yeah, indead. Seems that the problem is receiving a endless loop and receive a SIGINT on CTRL + C to stop. Could you be more specify at your last words? To how I can analysis the stacktrace.

Comment: The stack trace seems the expected one. The server is waiting for data.

Comment: You can attach to the process with gdb and add breakpoints to see if it is stuck in the reactor loop or if it is receiving something but not reacting properly. You can also use strace to check that: `strace -p <pid>`

Comment: We could move this discussion to a chat. If you guys would like please just give a reputation, missing that =(. Also, it may help analysis better, here is the others [Threads Bt](https://pastebin.com/26P7vQ20).

Comment: it seems like you have a dead lock, considering the others stack traces. Sorry, but I don't have time for a chat. Anyway, SO doesn't seem like the right place to do this and you are going to keep getting downvotes forever. C++ is already complicated by itself, I'd recommend you to learn how to debug/strace a simple code before starting to work on multithreading.

Answer (score 2):

`this=0x4`

Looks like you are dereferencing a null pointer somewhere (probably in your code), which is UB in C++.

One way to debug this issue is to rebuild with `-fsanitize=undefined` option. It is available in recent gcc and clang.

Or even rebuild with only `-fsanitize=null`, see [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html):

> ```
>        -fsanitize=null
>            This option enables pointer checking.  Particularly, the
>            application built with this option turned on will issue an
>            error message when it tries to dereference a NULL pointer, or
>            if a reference (possibly an rvalue reference) is bound to a
>            NULL pointer, or if a method is invoked on an object pointed
>            by a NULL pointer.
> ```

Comment: no SIGSEGV was received and the `this` may not be the right one as the code is optimized